# Creating a program that prints out the current day of the week based on EST time zone

Tags: c++, c, date, time, utc

The code I have created so far is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{


    int days, rmd;
    time_t seconds;

    seconds = time(NULL);

    days = (seconds/(60*60*24));



      rmd=days%7;

          if(rmd==4){
              printf("Monday \n");
          }
          if(rmd==5){
              printf("Tuesday \n");
          }
          if(rmd==6){
              printf("Wednesday \n");
          }
          if(rmd==0){
              printf("Thursday \n");
          }
          if(rmd==1){
              printf("Friday \n");
          }
          if(rmd==2){
              printf("Saturday \n");
          }
          if(rmd==3){
              printf("Sunday \n");
          }

return 0;
}
```

I understand that the time(NULL) returns the amount of seconds that have passed since the epoch which is jan 1, 1970. I also understand that jan 1 was a thursday. I also know that UTC timezone is 5 hours ahead of EST but i am not sure exactly how to take into account all these factors.

Answer (score 0):

If possible (e.g., you're not restricted by a homework assignment from using it), consider using stftime:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/

%A will give you the day of the week.

Comment: thanks for responding and yea im pretty sure im not allowed to use that command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localtime()` and `strftime()` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
   time_t rawtime;
   struct tm *info;
   char buffer[100];

   time(&rawtime);

   info = localtime(&rawtime);
   strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%A", info);
   printf("Current weekday: %s\n", buffer);

   return 0;
}
```

If the weekday name needs to be customized, you can also manually use `info->tm_wday`, which represents day of the week, range 0 to 6.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I cannot use something that complex to do this question for my class, for example im pretty sure i cant use pointers.